# Display another page when viewed from mobile

Tags: html, web, responsive-design

I have two web pages:
mobile.html with mobile.css and desktop.html with desktop.css.

How can I make a redirect to the mobile one (the default page is desktop.html) if screen size is less than 12″.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not recommended the best way is to use media queries to make your site responsive. By adding the class and detecting the browser width change.

```
<div class=" mobilehidden">
       <p>This text is hidden in mobile</p>
</div>
```

Now in Css put this line

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
.mobilehidden{
      display = none;
}
}
```

if you want to do this then you can use JavaScript for this. You can also use php ,css but JavaScript is easier. Simply use this inside script tag

```
if (screen.width <= 700) {
     document.location = "samplepage.html";
}
```

If you are using bootstrap there is a class for this

```
.visible-xs-* 
.visible-sm-*
```

The mentioned above sm is for tablets whereas xs is for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with PHP, using a lightweight class such as [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect). Once downloaded and added to the server in the root of your website, you can then use this code to detect if the device is a mobile and set the location to the url of your mobile site:

```
<?php 
/* Change path info depending on your file locations */
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: http://mobile.example1.com/');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Other devices can be detected and further examples can be found [here](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples)

Answer (score -2):

You dont have to change the page but just use bootstrap for making page responsive i hope you know bootstrap if you don't see learning tutorial in youtube.

Comment: It is responsive, but the content is totally different for the mobile and desktop version.  So responsive design is not the problem.

Comment: This does not answer the question.